# rearrange data.frame to get the sequential order of products

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
df <- data.frame(client = c("client1", "client1", "client2", "client3", "client3"),
                 product = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "A"),
                 purchase_Date = c("2010-03-22", "2010-02-02", "2009-03-02", "2011-04-05", "2012-11-01"))
df$purchase_Date <- as.Date(df$purchase_Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

which looks like this:

```
   client product purchase_Date
1 client1       A    2010-03-02
2 client1       B    2010-02-02
3 client2       A    2009-03-02
4 client3       D    2011-04-05
5 client3       A    2012-11-01
```

which I would like to rearrange like this:

```
   client purchase1 purchase2
1 client1         B         A
2 client2         A      <NA>
3 client3         D         A
```

so I would like to find out which product was the first one, second one, third one and so on, each person ordered by the purchase-Date. I can easily get each one individually using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .SD[order(-purchase_Date), product][1], by = client]
```

for the first one. but I have no idea how to efficiently get the desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution (if you have more than 10 purchases, then I'd recommend avoiding using `paste0` and just use `indx := seq_len(.N)` instead as it could potentially mess up the purchase order)

```
setDT(df)[order(purchase_Date), indx := paste0("purchase", seq_len(.N)), by = client]
dcast(df, client ~ indx, value.var = "product")
#     client purchase1 purchase2
# 1: client1         B         A
# 2: client2         A        NA
# 3: client3         D         A
```

---

Comparison between `frank()` and `order()` approaches to create `indx` col:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45L); 
dt = data.table(client = sample(paste("client", 1:1e4, sep=""), 1e6, TRUE))
dt[, `:=`(product = sample(paste("p", 1:200, sep=""), .N, FALSE), 
          purchase_Date = as.Date(sample(14610:16586, .N, FALSE), 
           origin = "1970-01-01")), by=client]

system.time(dt[order(purchase_Date), indx := seq_len(.N), by = client])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.19    0.02    0.20 
system.time(dt[, purch_rank := frank(purchase_Date, ties.method = "dense"), by=client])
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.94    0.00    3.98
```

Comment: This, I find is more efficient as it avoids a call to `frank()` for each `by`. `seq_len()` should be very negligible... would be great to benchmark!

Comment: Just benchmarked on a million rows with 10000 clients - `frank = 2.6s` vs `order() = 0.5s`. Added [FR #1197](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1197).

Answer (score 4):

A dplyr/tidyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(client) %>%
  mutate(purch_rank = dense_rank(purchase_Date)) %>%
  select(-purchase_Date) %>%
  spread(purch_rank, product)
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#   client 1  2
#1 client1 B  A
#2 client2 A NA
#3 client3 D  A
```

And a possible data.table approach:

```
library(data.table) #v 1.9.5+ currently from GitHub for "frank"
setDT(df)[, purch_rank := frank(purchase_Date, ties.method = "dense"), by=client]
dcast(df, client ~ purch_rank, value.var = "product")
#    client 1  2
#1: client1 B  A
#2: client2 A NA
#3: client3 D  A
```

Comment: I am sorry, my solution is very similar to your. I was occupied to figure it out  I did't notice it.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the obvious of just adding a rank!... oh man the working day has been to long

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(client) %>%
  select(-purchase_Date) %>%
  mutate(purchase = seq_along(product)) %>%
  spread(purchase, product)
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

   client 1  2
1 client1 A  B
2 client2 A NA
3 client3 D  A
```

A slightly different approach with a different output would be with the `reshape2` package. Just use the previous code except the last line that will be replaced by this one:

```
dcast(client ~ product)
Using purchase as value column: use value.var to override.
   client A  B  D
1 client1 1  2 NA
2 client2 1 NA NA
3 client3 2 NA  1
```

Comment: Your dplyr results are incorrect because you are not using the "purchase_Date" information.

Comment: I know, that's why I said that is a different approach. The output doesn't shows the products purchased (which is a variable in this case) but the ranking it has. Not answer the question of course, but it might be helpful maybe.

Comment: Are you also talking about the first approach in your answer?

Comment: I know that's "wrong" that's why I said "a different approach with a different outpu", it was supposed to just give you another way to figure the problem out.